# save jquery drag and drop position relative to parent DIV?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, position, draggable

I am using php and jquery-ui for saving drag and drop position. my problem is its saving top, left position which varies when viewing on a wider screen!

how can I save the position realative to parent element?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this kind of problem i have done something like :

I save the position in db using

```
parent = $('#theParentElement');
positionX = (parseInt(ui.draggable.css('left'))) / parent.width();
positionY = (parseInt(ui.draggable.css('top'))) / parent.height();
```

And then when i set the position from db on another client screen.

```
$("#elmtToPosition").css({
        'left':positionX * parent.width(),
        'top':positionY * parent.height()
        });
```

It works for me, try to adapt it.